Jupyter Notebook Kernel dying constantly
I have been writing a code in Jupyter Notebook the whole day but the Kernel keeps on dying again and again. This mainly happened because of Openml library when I executed this code
credit_data = openml.datasets.get_dataset(31)
X, y, _, _ = credit_data.get_data(target=credit_data.default_target_attribute)

These two lines are having issues and whenever I run it the Kernel dies and restarts. I have been searching the whole internet for the solution but I cant find it. I even increase the max_buffer_size in the config but still it doesnt work. The dataset itself is not that big. The thing is its working on Google Colab and Pycharm. But not in Jupyter Notebook or Spyder. I have no idea why. Please someone help
I wanted to fetch data from the dataset id 31. But Kernel is dying and restarting

your commands throw 'invalid syntax' , copy/paste your actual code not just those two lines along with all log/error messages thrown . I have pasted the output from my own attempt below .

does this work from a command line session ?   ,
try restarting your jupyter session  ,
try rebooting your host

As mentioned, session output for reference.
Python 3.12.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb 16 2024, 20:50:58) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openml
>>> crdata=openml.datasets.get_dataset(31)
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: Starting from Version 0.15 `download_data`, `download_qualities`, and `download_features_meta_data` will all be ``False`` instead of ``True`` by default to enable lazy loading. To disable this message until version 0.15 explicitly set `download_data`, `download_qualities`, and `download_features_meta_data` to a bool while calling `get_dataset`.
>>> crdata.get_data(target=crdata.default_target_attribute)
(    checking_status  duration                  credit_history              purpose  credit_amount    savings_status  employment  installment_commitment     personal_status  ... property_magnitude  age other_payment_plans   housing existing_credits                        job  num_dependents own_telephone  foreign_worker
0                <0         6  critical/other existing credit             radio/tv         1169.0  no known savings         >=7                       4         male single  ...        real estate   67                none       own                2                    skilled               1           yes             yes
1          0<=X<200        48                   existing paid             radio/tv         5951.0              <100      1<=X<4                       2  female div/dep/mar  ...        real estate   22                none       own                1                    skilled               1          none             yes
2       no checking        12  critical/other existing credit            education         2096.0              <100      4<=X<7                       2         male single  ...        real estate   49                none       own                1         unskilled resident               2          none             yes
3                <0        42                   existing paid  furniture/equipment         7882.0              <100      4<=X<7                       2         male single  ...     life insurance   45                none  for free                1                    skilled               2          none             yes
4                <0        24              delayed previously              new car         4870.0              <100      1<=X<4                       3         male single  ...  no known property   53                none  for free                2                    skilled               2          none             yes
..              ...       ...                             ...                  ...            ...               ...         ...                     ...                 ...  ...                ...  ...                 ...       ...              ...                        ...             ...           ...             ...
995     no checking        12                   existing paid  furniture/equipment         1736.0              <100      4<=X<7                       3  female div/dep/mar  ...        real estate   31                none       own                1         unskilled resident               1          none             yes
996              <0        30                   existing paid             used car         3857.0              <100      1<=X<4                       4        male div/sep  ...     life insurance   40                none       own                1  high qualif/self emp/mgmt               1           yes             yes
997     no checking        12                   existing paid             radio/tv          804.0              <100         >=7                       4         male single  ...                car   38                none       own                1                    skilled               1          none             yes
998              <0        45                   existing paid             radio/tv         1845.0              <100      1<=X<4                       4         male single  ...  no known property   23                none  for free                1                    skilled               1           yes             yes
999        0<=X<200        45  critical/other existing credit             used car         4576.0        100<=X<500  unemployed                       3         male single  ...                car   27                none       own                1                    skilled               1          none             yes

[1000 rows x 20 columns], 0      good
1       bad
2      good
3      good
4       bad
       ... 
995    good
996    good
997    good
998     bad
999    good
Name: class, Length: 1000, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): ['good' < 'bad'], [True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True], ['checking_status', 'duration', 'credit_history', 'purpose', 'credit_amount', 'savings_status', 'employment', 'installment_commitment', 'personal_status', 'other_parties', 'residence_since', 'property_magnitude', 'age', 'other_payment_plans', 'housing', 'existing_credits', 'job', 'num_dependents', 'own_telephone', 'foreign_worker'])
>>> 


NB: same works from jupyter notebook

It doesn't show any error message. Just restarts kernel as it said kernel has died

and if you do it outside of jupyter notebook - as previously requested .

It worked outside of Jupyter. But I found the problem I think. The conda was running in 3.11.4 which didnt let me run it. But when I ran it on my custom environment (which was also running on my Pycharm) using 3.12.3. It worked. I think its some issue or bug with conda in my laptop.
